# Launching run docker from cloud-init incorrectly prefixes "docker.io" to image name

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, cloud-init

I am starting a GCE server with a cloudinit file, that calls a docker image.  On startup, pulling the docker image fails, but if I run the same service upon logging in it succeeds.  I would like it to work upon launch.

Looking at the service logs, it seems that it is incorrectly prefixing the docker pull with `docker.io` and so failing the job.

Is there something I could be doing to prevent this?  Do I perhaps need to wait or check for something else to load before trying the docker pull?

Here is my cloud-init file:

```
#cloud-config

users:
- name: shinyuser
  uid: 2000

write_files:
- path: /etc/systemd/system/shinyserver.service
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Shiny server

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name=vdshinyserver -p 80:3838 -v /home/shinyuser/shinyapps/:/srv/shiny-server/ -v /home/shinyuser/srv/shinylog/:/var/log/ rocker/shiny
    ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop vdshinyserver

runcmd:
- systemctl daemon-reload
- systemctl start shinyserver.service
```

And here are the logs:

```
mark@xxxshiny ~ $ sudo journalctl -u shinyserver
-- Logs begin at Wed 2016-10-05 08:39:06 UTC, end at Wed 2016-10-05 08:39:46 UTC. --
Oct 05 08:39:11 xxxshiny docker[1016]: Unable to find image 'rocker/shiny:latest' locally
Oct 05 08:39:26 xxxshiny docker[1016]: Pulling repository docker.io/rocker/shiny
Oct 05 08:39:31 xxxshiny docker[1016]: /usr/bin/docker: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/rocker/shiny.
Oct 05 08:39:31 xxxshiny docker[1016]: See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
Oct 05 08:39:31 xxxshiny docker[1045]: Error response from daemon: No such container: vdshinyserver

mark@visit-dubai-shiny ~ $ sudo systemctl start shinyserver.service
mark@visit-dubai-shiny ~ $ sudo journalctl -u shinyserver
...
Oct 05 08:42:22 xxxshiny docker[1117]: Unable to find image 'rocker/shiny:latest' locally
Oct 05 08:42:23 xxxshiny docker[1117]: latest: Pulling from rocker/shiny
Oct 05 08:42:23 xxxshiny docker[1117]: a84f66826a7f: Pulling fs layer
Oct 05 08:42:23 xxxshiny docker[1117]: aaf7c0da390d: Pulling fs layer
...etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my cloudinit to match that at the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/) to include a requirement of `docker.service` in the file, and it now works:

```
#cloud-config

users:
- name: shinyuser
  uid: 2000

write_files:
- path: /etc/systemd/system/shinyserver.service
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=VisitDubai Shiny server for reporting
    Requires=docker.service
    After=docker.service

    [Service]
    Restart=always
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name=vdshinyserver -p 80:3838 -v /home/shinyuser/shinyapps/:/srv/shiny-server/ -v /home/shinyuser/srv/shinylog/:/var/log/ rocker/shiny
    ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop vdshinyserver
```

Comment: I had also added the `Requires` and `After`, turns out that the the `Restart=always` is important to.